# Using $watch and $emit to update a model object in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In our app we have a rather complex model object that is initialized by several calls to the backend. We have done our own implementation of "dirty" checks, i.e. we watch for any changes to the model object and only offer the user the chance to save their changes when we know changes have really been made after the model object was initialized in the beginning.

The "dirty" flag is automatically raised by a `$watch` function that watches the part of the model object that may change due to the user's actions. We have also a function for clearing the flag after we have done the initialization (which of course changes the model's state and triggers the watchers), implemented with an `$emit` call.

So, the idea is to follow these steps:

1. Initialize the model with several calls to the backend
2. Clear the "dirty" flag
3. Watch for changes to the model object, and if one happens, raise the flag

However, now we have a problem that the model seems modified immediately after the initialization already. If I've traced the problem correctly, this happens because the `$emit` call to clear the flag is run before the `$watch` launches.

**What would be the best way to make sure the flag is cleared after the watcher has already been called?**

Also, this problem has appeared only a while back, and might be related to us upgrading to AngularJS 1.2 - but this might also just be a coincidence.

**EDIT:** The listener for the flag-clearing call uses `$evalAsync` to postpone the change, as follows:

```
$scope.$on('resetModelChangeCounter', function(event) {
  event.targetScope.$evalAsync(function() {
    ourModel.setUnchanged();
  });
});
```

**EDIT #2:** Here's a fiddle showing the behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/LVrVj/1/

Comment: A JSFiddle/Plunker with a minimum repro would help.

Comment: Definitely. Added one now, and it shows the problem: clearing the flag gets called before it's set, thus leaving the flag on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, you basically trigger two things which AngularJS has to procces: the signal and the watch.

```
$scope.exampleModel.internalObject.secondKey = "anotherValue";
// this is initialization, so we don't want the change to enable saving
$scope.$emit('resetModelChangeCounter');
```

Are you expecting these events to happen in the same order as you trigger them? I would not trust that assumption, and in this case the digest cycle seem to trigger the watch before the signal is processed.

Anyways, you can wrap the signal in a new timeout, and it will be processed after the digest cycle is finshed and the watch has been triggered.

I updated the fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/LVrVj/2/

Comment: The real code was actually written by someone else, but I came to the same conclusion - and that the reaction to the signal has that `$evalAsync` to force the desired order. But it seems it doesn't work anymore (perhaps due to something changing in the 1.2 version of Angular). Anyway, that `$timeout` in the emitting end seems to do the trick, and it also works without that `$evalAsync`. Thank you!

Comment: Since the emitted signal is actually sent from a couple of places, I moved the `$timeout` to the receiving end to avoid repetition, thus replacing the old `$evalAsync`: http://jsfiddle.net/LVrVj/3/ Just a small tweak. :)